# How to get the value of TextViews from an ArrayAdapter to another Class

Tags: android

In order to pass data from my Custom Adapter to another class I tried these two methods and none worked for me.

```
    String SGetNumVol=Num_Vol.getText().toString();
    String SGetComment=Commentaire.getText().toString();
    String SGetAirpDepart=Aeroport.getText().toString();
    String SGetDestination=Destination.getText().toString();
    String SGetCompanie=code_Compagnie.getText().toString();

    Intent intent =new Intent(c,DetailVol.class);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    GetNumVol= bundle.getString(SGetNumVol);
    GetComment= bundle.getString(SGetComment);
    GetAirpDepart= bundle.getString(SGetAirpDepart);
    GetDestination= bundle.getString(SGetDestination);
    GetCompanie= bundle.getString(SGetCompanie);
```

and recieving it like

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        String a =(String) b.get(CustomAdapter.GetAirpDepart);
        Airportdep.setText(a);
        String c =(String) b.get(CustomAdapter.GetDestination);
        dest.setText(c);

        String e =(String) b.get(CustomAdapter.GetNumVol);
        Num.setText(e);
        String f=(String) b.get(CustomAdapter.GetComment);
        com.setText(f);
        String j =(String) b.get(CustomAdapter.GetCompanie);
        Comp.setText(j);
    }
```

Second Method is like :

```
    //SecondTest
    Intent i = new Intent(c, DetailVol.class);
    String SGetNumVol=Num_Vol.getText().toString();
    String SGetComment=Commentaire.getText().toString();
    String SGetAirpDepart=Aeroport.getText().toString();
    String SGetDestination=Destination.getText().toString();
    String SGetCompanie=code_Compagnie.getText().toString();

    i.putExtra("SGetNumVol", SGetNumVol);
    i.putExtra("SGetComment", SGetComment);
    i.putExtra("SGetAirpDepart",SGetAirpDepart);
    i.putExtra("SGetDestination",SGetDestination);
    i.putExtra("SGetCompanie", SGetCompanie);
```

recieving :

```
      //SecondTest
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            NumVol= null;
             Comment= null;
            AirDepart= null;
             Destination= null;
            Companie= null;
        } else {
            NumVol= extras.getString("SGetNumVol");
            Comment= extras.getString("SGetComment");
            AirDepart= extras.getString("SGetAirpDepart");
            Destination= extras.getString("SGetDestination");
            Companie= extras.getString("SGetCompanie");
        }
    } else {
        NumVol= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("SGetNumVol");
        Comment= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("SGetComment");
        AirDepart= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("SGetAirpDepart");
        Destination= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("SGetDestination");
        Companie= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("SGetCompanie");
    }
```

The first returning NullPointerException and the second just pass without any error but it doesn't return values from Custom Adapter. I hope I explained it well, does anybody know how can I correct this?

Comment: Where does the data you display in your adapter come from? Can't you just pass around this data object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use sharedprefs just send the data with extras from one activity to other activity

add this in the adapter, convertView is inflated view, person is the item of the list

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Person p = getItem(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(_con,SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("DATA", p._fName);
            _con.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

second activity:

```
_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATA");
    _text.setText(data);
```

Comment: Thx u gave me a hint , i wasn't Setting Text in the second class that's why it's ignoring it , it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Set the value

  SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
               Editor editor = pref.edit();
               editor.putString("Vol", SGetNumVol);
               editor.putString("Comment", SGetComment);
               editor.apply();


    Get the value in another Class

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String vol = prefs.getString("Vol", "No name defined");
            String comment = prefs.getString("Comment", "No name defined");
```

Comment: Okey I'll Try it !

Comment: Not Really it's ignoring it just like the second methos of mine